# What do you know about how google/search engines see's/crawls PDF files?

Tags: seo, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do search engines crawl PDFs and if so are there any rules to follow when making them](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/do-search-engines-crawl-pdfs-and-if-so-are-there-any-rules-to-follow-when-making)

I have done this PDF's for online purposes and now they sometime appear in some google searches...that is not a problem, its ok, 
the problem is that google takes the title from the metadata **BUT does not take the description.** 
Instead it takes the first sentence from the PDF document(I think...not sure)

The only problem is that in my case all the PDF's have the same sentence in the begining...(some info on the cover of the PDF that is all the same on all my PDF's(40+ in total).

The only solution I found was to give up the info text from the cover page(page1) and then it would crawl to the next page where all the info is different and specifically relevant to that PDF...

Or as an alternative, kind of dirty, place a 2pt small text, same color as bg, so invisible to the naked eye...but readable by google crawlers... but I really don't like this solution as it would be visible if you select all text on page...

Did any of you encountered this issue before ? Any solutions ?

Maybe this question is not relevant to the GD questions but I think it will be helpfull for those handling PDF stuff in the online world...

Comment: Doesn't seem like an exact dupe to me: this post asks a specific question ("How to best influence the description shown by Google for PDF files?") which is not covered by the other question or its answers. (The closest thing I could find was point 8 behind [this link](http://searchengineland.com/eleven-tips-for-optimizing-pdfs-for-search-engines-12156).) Perhaps this question just needs a bit of editing to clarify its focus.