# Should I post my PDF library for SEO?

Tags: seo, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do search engines crawl PDFs and if so are there any rules to follow when making them](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/do-search-engines-crawl-pdfs-and-if-so-are-there-any-rules-to-follow-when-making)

When a Sales call comes in, the caller often says something like: 'I searched for 3 days before finding your product and it's exactly what I need!'

That's telling me that I need some SEO work.

We redid our website and streamlined it which removed many of our 'How-To' documents.

Since those PDF documents contain words that people might search for, I was wondering if 
I could add a 'Complete library' link to the bottom of a page that will load up the entire PDF library.

Would that help my ranking?